# weird higlighted lines I can't remove

Tags: edges

[image]

I don't really know 
kind of new to blender

Comment: Do you need to remove the highlights, or the edges themselves?

Answer (score 3):

These edges are [marked as sharp](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/edges.html#mark-sharp-and-clear-sharp).

To unmark them, simply select the edges (or all edges <kbd>A</kbd>), press <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to open up the edge popup menu and choose *Clear Sharp*.

[image: clear sharp]